# clean up rake db:migrate:status

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking at a production server that gives a lot of output from `rake db:migrate:status` like

```
database: important_production

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------

.
.
.
up     20140317065716  ********** NO FILE **********
up     20140317070243  Add userid to activities
.
.
.
```

I feel like it's bad practice to have this kind of 'no file' error since it prevents migrations downwards.  But it's also bad practice to mess up someone's production machine, isn't it.  Those two migrations listed above, the missing file one actually had it's migration deleted because it was a duplicate of the next down migration.

My resolution for this is to log into the db shell on the production machine, and run:

```
DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version = 20140317065716;
```

I'm not 100% this will work or not though and I can't find any supporting documentation on the process of repairing the migration chain for rails apps out there.  What are some advisements, caveats, and best practices here?